# Crontab is not running the code looks correct

Tags: python, cron

I am getting the crontab is installing message.

```
(base) jasonyao@Jasons-MBP ~ % crontab -l
* * * * * python /Users/jasonyao/Downloads/testrank.py

zsh: permission denied: /Users/jasonyao/Downloads # also getting this don't know if it's not running due to this..
```

here is my job. What I did was export the ipynb file as a py file including the code to run the code and append on an exisiting csv file. But the job is not running at all.

Comment: Do you have any messages in `mail`? (Type `mail` in the terminal). If not, have the job output log files (e.g., `python (script) > /path/to/a/logfile 2>&1`) and see what is output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the crontab for the root user (sudo crontab) or you can check out this block post about this permissions issues if you are using mac:
[Fix permissions issues](https://osxdaily.com/2020/04/27/fix-cron-permissions-macos-full-disk-access/)